# Planarize curves

Tags: modeling, modifiers

How can I planarize a group of Vertex from a curve, loop or Edge? I dont want to straight them. I want to remain the shape of the original curve but thinks in the new curve as "projected over the "BEST" plane that contents this group of Vertex

Un the same way, I would like to know how to align a group of Vertex to a target curve.

Thank in advance.

Comment: i think two example images would help (what you have, what you wanna have)